# Batch insert is throwing error with Quill.io with mariadb when using Monix

Tags: scala, mariadb, monix, quill.io

On mariadb 10.5.9 and scala 2.13 using `MysqlMonixJdbcContext` from getquill.io and trying to do a batch insert with

```
import io.getquill._
val ctx = new MysqlMonixJdbcContext(SnakeCase, "ctx")
import ctx._

val images: List[Image] = ...
run(
    liftQuery(images).map(i => query[Image].insert(i).onConflictIgnore)
)
```

```
case class Image(path: String, digest: String, size: Int, id: Option[Int])
```

```
CREATE TABLE `IMAGE` (
    `path` VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
    `digest` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `size` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_general_ci';

ALTER TABLE `IMAGE`
    ADD UNIQUE INDEX `uk_path` (`path`);
```

I get the following error

```
exception during macro expansion:
scala.reflect.macros.TypecheckException: Case class type io.getquill.Insert[Image] has no values
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Have you tried foreach instead of map?

Comment: Yup that works. I was trying to get the generated id in the batch hence used map